# How many fibonacci(2) calls are made when computing fibonnaci(7)?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, fibonacci

When you run Fib(7) how many calls are made to Fib(2)?

The algorithm is defined like this:

```
Algorithm Fib(n):

    if n = 0 or n = 1
        then f = n
        else f = Fib(n-1) + Fib(n - 2)
    endif
    return f
```

I think the answer is 7.

Comment: Have a look at [SICP video 1b @40m](http://youtu.be/dlbMuv-jix8?t=40m13s) and see the master draw the tree `fib(4)` does.

Comment: @NolanHodge: I'm not sure what was reportable about my comment. It's an interesting property of your question that the answer will always be another Fibonacci number.

Comment: Why not count them yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation of your pseudocode in Python (almost copy-paste):

```
def Fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        f = n
    else:
        f = Fib(n-1) + Fib(n - 2)
    return f

print Fib(7)
```

Now, I add the following lines:

```
if n == 2:
    print 'Fib(2)'
```

and the result is:

```
Fib(2)
Fib(2)
Fib(2)
Fib(2)
Fib(2)
Fib(2)
Fib(2)
Fib(2)
13
```

Which means that `Fib(2)` is called **8 times**.

Answer (score 2):

Let f(n) be the number of calls to Fib(2) when computing Fib(n).

Then, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 1, and for k > 3, f(k) = f(k-1) + f(k-2).

This is the same recurrence relation as Fib itself, and you get the solution f(k) = Fib(k-1). For the particular case k=7, you get the solution Fib(6) = 8.

This generalises: the number of calls to Fib(m) when computing Fib(n) is Fib(n-m+1) (assuming n >= m).

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, in Python:

```python
def fib(n):
    def fib2(n):
        count[n] = count.get(n,0)+1
        if n < 2:
            return n
        else:
            return fib2(n-1) + fib2(n-2)
    count = {}
    return fib2(n), [(c, count[c]) for c in sorted(count)]

print(fib(7))
```

prints

```python
=> (13, [(0, 8), (1, 13), (2, 8), (3, 5), (4, 3), (5, 2), (6, 1), (7, 1)])
    ===                   ======
```

so the result of fib(7) is *13* and fib(2) is called *8* times.